# NuGet package shows yellow exclamation mark

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, nuget, nuget-package

I just installed a package through NuGet, but it shows a yellow exclamation mark icon in my Solution Explorer, see screenshot below.

Why does this happen, and how can I resolve it?

[image]

Comment: There are no build errors

Comment: See my comment. An icon like that will have an accompanying **warning** in the Error List.

Comment: Even if there is no error message, you can trigger one by removing and adding this package again in some cases.

Comment: Did you install the package "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration"? Did this yellow exclamation display on a new asp.net-core project? Have you try to change the MSBuild project build output verbosity to Detailed or Diagnostic(Tools->Options->Projects and Solutions->Build and Run) to check the Error list?

Comment: Restart Visual Studio helped me

Comment: You could try to unload the project and load it back to solution. If doesn't help - reload NuGet cache and re-open the Visual Studio.

Comment: Thanks Alexander...

Comment: I was able to drop to command line and run `dotnet restore` from the folder containing my solution to resolve an issue where I was seeing the exclamation icon.

Comment: I have been getting these yellow warnings on dependencies, and builds did not yield any errors, warnings, or messages.  I think when people respond, they shouldn't assume.  I've flagged CodeCaster's comment as rude or abusive as it is snippy AND incorrect.  Had it been snippy and yielded correct information, I would upvote.

Comment: try to delete solution .vs folder and reload the solution.

Answer (score 31):

Many times it is just that Visual Studio is out of sync.  Closing the solution and re-opening will magically fix these errors in many cases.  It's easy enough that it should be one of the first things you try.

Comment: In other words: Did you try turning it off and on again?

Comment: Restarting Visual Studio (2019) fixed the issue for me. I didn't try reopening the solution without closing Visual Studio. DotNet Core 2.2.

Comment: Same thing here. Restarted VS 2019 and the exclamation marks were gone

Comment: Same thing here. Restarted VS 2022 and the exclamation marks were gone

Answer (score 2):

In my case I had to manually update **targetFramework** in **packages.config** where "problematic" nuget was referenced.

My steps:

1. I checked the path where NuGet is installed
2. I searched config where the NuGet is referenced within the solution
3. I manually changed **targetFramework** according the last segment/directory of NuGet's installation path
   [image: my screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes this can happen somewhat persistently after changing the `TargetFramework(s)` on a project that has already been loaded into Visual Studio. In my experience, the easiest way to ensure things are working correctly after changing the TFMs on a project is to close the solution, manually remove all the relevant `bin`/`obj` directories as well as the `.vs` folder next to the solution file.

Comment: Removing "bin" and "obj" was enough

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old thread, but still, it happens even with VS 2022, when you move the project to a different physical location even with the same name.
In many cases, absolutely all the dependencies are suddenly marked with a yellow or brown exclamation mark triangle.
One solution is to remove one dependency and reload it via NuGet. Updating a dependency if possible does the same, and in both cases, apparently forces VS to get the right location of the dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

For me i had this while using flaui dependency which was not matching the TargetFramework after changing from net6.0 to net6.0-windows it worked.

[csproj file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sACKK.png)