# All .Net Core projects showing yellow exclamation mark / triangle

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core

I have a related issue to this question [NuGet package shows yellow exclamation mark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43394276/nuget-package-shows-yellow-exclamation-mark). However, none of the comments help me.

I have installed .Net Core SDK (shown in the console screenshot)

[image]

When I create a new .Net core project; doesn't matter if it's a web site, web api or console application - I get the same result.

The steps I take are as follows:

[image]

[image]

I get the following - every single reference has the yellow exclamation.

[image]

I am running the most recent version of Visual Studio (at this time) 15.4.1

If i use the command line to create the project then everything is fine. However, if i open a cloned project created by another developer I get the yellow exclamation mark.

Any idea what I have incorrectly set up?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

try "dotnet restore" command

This will restore all the packages.

make sure you have updated version of Runtime, SDK, and tools from the below link
because updates should fix this issue.

https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/core

Comment: Well, that was simple! Thanks so much!

Comment: Hi, Darren id you like the post don't forget to forget to vote for the post this is helpful for other people also.

Comment: unfortunately did not work for me. using .net core 2.0

Comment: Hi, John, do you have circular references to another library in your project. That's the other reason you could have a yellow icon. but as far as I know, it will not stop you from building and running your project. if that's not your case. send more doc and snapshot so I can replicated in my PC and find solution...

Comment: I just created a brand new dot net core 3.1 project with Angular template and I cannot get rid of yellow exclamation from the dependencies folder.  Also, when I try to compile I get "node --version" exited with code 9009.  Node.js is required to build and run this project....

Answer (score 0):

The yellow triangles on all my dependencies appeared right after I renamed my project and solution.  I wasn't able to get them to restore using the cmd above.  I ended up removing all of the dependencies, readded them and the triangles went away.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30121858)